# Apache httpd: Inject announcement banner into every page including reverse proxy

Tags: html, apache, reverse-proxy, inject

I want to inject a banner announcing planned maintenance a few days in advance into every web page served. The apache has a few local pages, but mostly acts as reverse proxy of several web applications. This question has two parts:

1. How do I configure Apache httpd 2.4 so that some static HTML is injected into both locally served pages as well as pages served by a separate tomcat or maybe a Zope server ?
2. How to write a HTML snippet that gives a noticeable warning ("Maintenance Monday 8-9am, all services unavailable") without interfering with various CSS used by the proxied apps, and maybe even not breaking e.g. Single Page Apps

Thanks in advance,
Yours,
Steffen